# Nested CSS classes

Tags: css

There is a way to do this in `css` ?

```
.main-div {

   .input { ... }
   .select { ... }
   .a { ... }
   .li { ... }
   ....

}
```

Comment: You can do something similar with a CSS preprocessor, like SASS or LESS.

Comment: What would be the outcome of what you are intending? Perhaps there *is* a way, just not like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need a preprocessor language like Sass or LESS. Then you could do exactly that.

Comment: "Sass", not "SAS". :)

Comment: I blame spell check... correction made. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a CSS-preprocessor like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/). But there is currently no way to accomplish this in pure CSS.